# ImportError: cannot import name 'Index' from 'landing.views'

Tags: python, html, django, importerror

So I was following a tutorial on Youtube, and here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rpi0Ne1nMdk and I got to 12:46 when he got to importing Index. I hit run, but I received a Syntax Error instead. Here is a sample of my code:

```
from django.urls import path
from landing.views import Index


urlpatterns = [
  path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'), 
]
```

when I hit run, this returned:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Index' from 'landing.views' (/home/runner/red-chilli-media/landing/views.py)
```

If it looks weird, it's because I'm using replit.
I used the django project, and the language is Python/HTML.
if any information is missing, please tell me.
The error is in Python, as you can clearly see.

Comment: That's not a syntax error, you simply never defined a variable named `Index` in the `view` module.

Comment: It's not a variable, it's an import module

Comment: In the module/file `.../landing/views.py` is there anything named `Index` ? Or at least something like `from something import *` ? Otherwise this importerror will apear

Comment: @Hellotheepic111 add your landing.views  file here